# Catch URL protocol to an app that isn't installed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a URL protocol that links to my twitter profile in iOS.  But I would like it to fall back to Safari if the user does not have the Twitter app installed.  How would I do that?  This is the code I am using right now:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"twitter://user?screen_name=ecnepsnai";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `-canOpenURL:` method of `UIApplication`.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"twitter://user?screen_name=ecnepsnai";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can test if the "twitter://" URL can be handled using:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
    // fallback
}
```